# Golang gin receive json data and image

Tags: json, go, multipartform-data, go-gin

I have this code for request handler:

```
func (h *Handlers) UpdateProfile() gin.HandlerFunc {
    type request struct {
        Username    string `json:"username" binding:"required,min=4,max=20"`
        Description string `json:"description" binding:"required,max=100"`
    }

    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        var updateRequest request

        if err := c.BindJSON(&updateRequest); err != nil {
            var validationErrors validator.ValidationErrors

            if errors.As(err, &validationErrors) {
                validateErrors := base.BindingError(validationErrors)
                c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": validateErrors})
            } else {
                c.AbortWithError(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
            }

            return
        }

        avatar, err := c.FormFile("avatar")
        if err != nil {
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
                "error": "image not contains in request",
            })
            return
        }

        log.Print(avatar)

        if avatar.Size > 3<<20 { // if avatar size more than 3mb
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
                "error": "image is too large",
            })
            return
        }

        file, err := avatar.Open()
        if err != nil {
            c.AbortWithError(http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
        }

        session := sessions.Default(c)
        id := session.Get("sessionId")
        log.Printf("ID type: %T", id)

        err = h.userService.UpdateProfile(fmt.Sprintf("%v", id), file, updateRequest.Username, updateRequest.Description)
        if err != nil {
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{})
            return
        }

        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusNoContent, gin.H{"message": "succesfull update"})
    }
}
```

And I have this unit test for this handler:

```
func TestUser_UpdateProfile(t *testing.T) {
    type testCase struct {
        name               string
        image              io.Reader
        username           string
        description        string
        expectedStatusCode int
    }

    router := gin.Default()

    memStore := memstore.NewStore([]byte("secret"))
    router.Use(sessions.Sessions("session", memStore))

    userGroup := router.Group("user")
    repo := user.NewMemory()
    service := userService.New(repo)
    userHandlers.Register(userGroup, service)

    testImage := make([]byte, 100)
    rand.Read(testImage)
    image := bytes.NewReader(testImage)

    testCases := []testCase{
        {
            name:               "Request With Image",
            image:              image,
            username:           "bobik",
            description:        "wanna be sharik",
            expectedStatusCode: http.StatusNoContent,
        },
        {
            name:               "Request Without Image",
            image:              nil,
            username:           "sharik",
            description:        "wanna be bobik",
            expectedStatusCode: http.StatusNoContent,
        },
    }

    for _, tc := range testCases {
        t.Run(tc.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            body := &bytes.Buffer{}
            writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)

            imageWriter, err := writer.CreateFormFile("avatar", "test_avatar.jpg")
            if err != nil {
                t.Fatal(err)
            }

            if _, err := io.Copy(imageWriter, image); err != nil {
                t.Fatal(err)
            }

            data := map[string]interface{}{
                "username":    tc.username,
                "description": tc.description,
            }
            jsonData, err := json.Marshal(data)
            if err != nil {
                t.Fatal(err)
            }

            jsonWriter, err := writer.CreateFormField("json")
            if err != nil {
                t.Fatal(err)
            }

            if _, err := jsonWriter.Write(jsonData); err != nil {
                t.Fatal(err)
            }

            writer.Close()

            // Creating request
            req := httptest.NewRequest(
                http.MethodPost,
                "http://localhost:8080/user/account/updateprofile",
                body,
            )
            req.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
            log.Print(req)

            w := httptest.NewRecorder()
            router.ServeHTTP(w, req)

            assert.Equal(t, tc.expectedStatusCode, w.Result().StatusCode)
        })
    }
}
```

During test I have this error:
Error #01: invalid character '-' in numeric literal

And here is request body (I am printing it with log.Print(req)):

```
&{POST http://localhost:8080/user/account/updateprofile HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Type:[multipart/form-data; boundary=30b24345de9d8d83ecbdd146262d86894c45b4f3485e4615553621fd2035]] {--30b24345de9d8d83ecbdd146262d86894c45b4f3485e4615553621fd2035
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar"; filename="test_avatar.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


--30b24345de9d8d83ecbdd146262d86894c45b4f3485e4615553621fd2035
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"

{"description":"wanna be bobik","username":"sharik"}
--30b24345de9d8d83ecbdd146262d86894c45b4f3485e4615553621fd2035--
} <nil> 414 [] false localhost:8080 map[] map[] <nil> map[] 192.0.2.1:1234 http://localhost:8080/user/account/updateprofile <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil>}
```

First I just have strings as json data and converted it to bytes. When error appeared I converted json data using json.Marshal, but it didn't work out. I want to parse json data with c.Bind and parse given image with c.FormFile, does it possible?

Upd. I replaced code to get avatar first, and then get json by Bind structure. Now I have EOF error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

We can define a struct to receive the json data and image file at the same time (pay attention to the field tags):

```golang
var updateRequest struct {
    Avatar *multipart.FileHeader `form:"avatar" binding:"required"`
    User   struct {
        Username    string `json:"username" binding:"required,min=4,max=20"`
        Description string `json:"description" binding:"required,max=100"`
    } `form:"user" binding:"required"`
}

// c.ShouldBind will choose binding.FormMultipart based on the Content-Type header.
// We call c.ShouldBindWith to make it explicitly.
if err := c.ShouldBindWith(&updateRequest, binding.FormMultipart); err != nil {
    _ = c.AbortWithError(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
    return
}
```

---

#### Can gin parse other content type in `multipart/form-data` automatically?

For example, `xml` or `yaml`.

The current gin (@1.9.0) does not parse `xml` or `yaml` in `multipart/form-data` automatically. `json` is lucky because gin happens to parse the form field value using `json.Unmarshal` when the target field is a struct or map. See [binding.setWithProperType](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/a889c58de78711cb9b53de6cfcc9272c8518c729/binding/form_mapping.go#L234-L241).

We can parse them ourself like this (`updateRequest.Event` is the string value from the form):

```golang
var event struct {
    At     time.Time `xml:"time" binding:"required"`
    Player string    `xml:"player" binding:"required"`
    Action string    `xml:"action" binding:"required"`
}

if err := binding.XML.BindBody([]byte(updateRequest.Event), &event); err != nil {
    _ = c.AbortWithError(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
    return
}
```

(Please don't get confused with `xml` in an `application/xml` request or `yaml` in an `application/x-yaml` request. This is only required when the `xml` content or `yaml` content is in a `multipart/form-data` request).

#### Misc

1. `c.BindJSON` can not be used to read json from `multipart/form-data` because it assumes that the request body starts with a valid json. But it's starts with a boundary, which looks like `--30b24345d...`. That's why it failed with error message `invalid character '-' in numeric literal`.
2. Calling `c.BindJSON` after `c.FormFile("avatar")` does not work because calling `c.FormFile` makes the whole request body being read. And `c.BindJSON` has nothing to read later. That's why you see the EOF error.

#### The demo in a single runnable file

Here is the full demo. Run with `go test ./... -v -count 1`:

```golang
package m

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
    "time"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin/binding"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func handle(c *gin.Context) {
    var updateRequest struct {
        Avatar *multipart.FileHeader `form:"avatar" binding:"required"`
        User   struct {
            Username    string `json:"username" binding:"required,min=4,max=20"`
            Description string `json:"description" binding:"required,max=100"`
        } `form:"user" binding:"required"`
        Event string `form:"event" binding:"required"`
    }

    // c.ShouldBind will choose binding.FormMultipart based on the Content-Type header.
    // We call c.ShouldBindWith to make it explicitly.
    if err := c.ShouldBindWith(&updateRequest, binding.FormMultipart); err != nil {
        _ = c.AbortWithError(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", updateRequest)

    var event struct {
        At     time.Time `xml:"time" binding:"required"`
        Player string    `xml:"player" binding:"required"`
        Action string    `xml:"action" binding:"required"`
    }

    if err := binding.XML.BindBody([]byte(updateRequest.Event), &event); err != nil {
        _ = c.AbortWithError(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", event)
}

func TestMultipartForm(t *testing.T) {
    testImage := make([]byte, 100)

    if _, err := rand.Read(testImage); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    image := bytes.NewReader(testImage)

    body := &bytes.Buffer{}
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)

    imageWriter, err := writer.CreateFormFile("avatar", "test_avatar.jpg")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    if _, err := io.Copy(imageWriter, image); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := writer.WriteField("user", `{"username":"bobik","description":"wanna be sharik"}`); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    xmlBody := `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <time>2023-02-14T19:04:12Z</time>
   <player>playerOne</player>
   <action>strike (miss)</action>
</root>`
    if err := writer.WriteField("event", xmlBody); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    writer.Close()

    req := httptest.NewRequest(
        http.MethodPost,
        "http://localhost:8080/update",
        body,
    )
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", req)

    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    c, engine := gin.CreateTestContext(w)
    engine.POST("/update", handle)
    c.Request = req
    engine.HandleContext(c)

    assert.Equal(t, 200, w.Result().StatusCode)
}
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer! I have a question, why are you using WriteField instead of CreateFormField? I read that difference between them not so big. In 1 case it writes to body key and value, in 2 case it does the same but also writes Content-Type and Content-Disposition. Am I right?

Comment: `WriteField` calls `CreateFormField` under the neath. It's almost the same in our use case. I used it just because it save me several lines of code. ^_^.

Comment: And also may you help me implement session set here pls? :) Because I got this error: panic: Key "github.com/gin-contrib/sessions" does not exist [recovered]
        panic: Key "github.com/gin-contrib/sessions" does not exist
When I added this code: 
// Create a Gin context from the test request and recorder
   c, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(w)
   c.Request = req
   session := sessions.Default(c)
   session.Set("sessionId", uuid.New())
   session.Save()

Comment: @Whilez See the new answer below.

Comment: And is there a way maybe to send avatar in form, and json data as json body? Or it doesn't possible?

Comment: And also if user gives me nil avatar, I replace it with default. So I think it would be better to set nil avatar as []byte{}.

Comment: `So I think it would be better to set nil avatar as []byte{}`. I don't have any idea about this. I think we both agree that the demo is just for showing the idea. You should modify it according to your project requirement.

Comment: @Whilez Sorry that I made a mistake here. In fact, gin can parse the file and the json data from `multipart/form-data` request at the same time. I have updated the answer to show how to do it. You can check section 3 in the answer.

Comment: No problem! I saw it, but didn't mind. I made something like that:
type request struct {
  Avatar      *multipart.FileHeader `form:"avatar" binding:"required"`
  Username    string                `form:"username" binding:"required,min=4,max=20"`
  Description string                `form:"description" binding:"required,max=100"`
 }

Comment: Also should I update my question to corrected code which works well?

Comment: I think you don't need to update the question. Most of the time, users will find answer from the accepted answer. BTW, I'm editing my answer to add a "TL;DR" part at the top.

Comment: I think the binding you showed can not binding to a json data in a form field. Have you tested it?

Comment: I tested it, all works OK. But for each field I need writer.WriteField("username", tc.username) for example. That's not as you wrote, but all works great for me.

Comment: Got it. But please note that it's not sent as json on the wire.

Comment: OK, thanks. Also what benefits of using BindWith over Bind? And why are you using ShouldBind instead of Bind?

Comment: `Bind` calls `binding.Default` to select a binding engine and then `MustBindWith`; `BindWith` was deprecated; `ShouldBind` calls `binding.Default` to select a binding engine and then `ShouldBindWith`. `MustBindWith` calls `ShouldBindWith` and `AbortWithError` if there is an error.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to manage your needs with the following solution. Let's start with the production code.

#### `handlers.go` file

```golang
package handlers

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type Request struct {
    Username string `form:"username" binding:"required,min=4,max=20"`
    Avatar []byte
}

func UpdateProfile(c *gin.Context) {
    avatarFileHeader, err := c.FormFile("avatar")
    if err != nil {
        c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
        return
    }

    file, err := avatarFileHeader.Open()
    if err != nil {
        c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
        return
    }
    data, err := io.ReadAll(file)
    if err != nil {
        c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
        return
    }
    var req Request
    req.Avatar = data
    if err := c.ShouldBind(&req); err != nil {
        c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
        return
    }
}
```

Here, there are a couple of things to be aware of:

1. I simplified the solution just for the sake of the demo.
2. I put the annotation `form:"username"` on the `Username` field. Thanks to this, `gin` knows where to look for the field in the incoming HTTP Request.
3. Then, to map the form fields, I used the built-in method `ShouldBind` that takes care of the rest.

Now, let's switch to the test code.

#### `handlers_test.go` file

The test file builds and runs only a single test. However, you can surely expand on it.

```golang
package handlers

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "net/textproto"
    "os"
    "testing"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestUpdateProfile(t *testing.T) {
    gin.SetMode(gin.TestMode)
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    c := gin.CreateTestContextOnly(w, gin.Default())

    // multipart writer creation
    body := new(bytes.Buffer)
    multipartWriter := multipart.NewWriter(body)

    // add file
    fileHeader := make(textproto.MIMEHeader)
    fileHeader.Set("Content-Disposition", fmt.Sprintf(`form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"`, "avatar", "avatar.png"))
    fileHeader.Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    writer, _ := multipartWriter.CreatePart(fileHeader)
    file, _ := os.Open("IvanPesenti.png")
    defer file.Close()
    io.Copy(writer, file)

    // add form field
    writer, _ = multipartWriter.CreateFormField("username")
    writer.Write([]byte("ivan_pesenti"))

    // please be sure to close the writer before launching the HTTP Request
    multipartWriter.Close()
    c.Request = &http.Request{
        Header: make(http.Header),
    }
    c.Request.Method = http.MethodPost
    c.Request.Header.Set("Content-Type", multipartWriter.FormDataContentType())
    c.Request.Body = io.NopCloser(body)
    c.ContentType()

    UpdateProfile(c)

    assert.Equal(t, 200, w.Code)
}
```

Here, we can summarize what's going on in the following list:

1. I created the HTTP Request, Response, and a Gin engine to handle the test.
2. I created a `multipart/form-data` request to pass to the `UpdateProfile` Gin handler.
3. I read a local image and set the form file `avatar`.
4. I set the form field `username` with the value `ivan_pesenti`.
5. I closed the `multipartWriter` before issuing the request. This is imperative!

The rest of the test file should be pretty straight-forward, so I won't spend extra time explaining it!

Let me know whether it's clear or you have other questions, thanks!

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer, but I have one question. I think that if I have session handler in my function, I can't use gin test context. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

> And also may you help me implement session set here pls? :) Because I got this error:
>
> ```
> panic: Key "github.com/gin-contrib/sessions" does not exist
> ```
>
> When I added this code:
>
> ```golang
> // Create a Gin context from the test request and recorder
> c, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(w)
> c.Request = req
> session := sessions.Default(c)
> session.Set("sessionId", uuid.New())
> session.Save()
> ```

This is a new question that has nothing to do with the original question. So I will post a new answer for it (maybe we should create a new question instead. I will move this answer to the new question if one is created).

The error is caused by the fact that the session is not added to the context yet. I will try to explain how session works generally with q sequence diagram.

[image: session sequence]

You see that before the session middleware is executed for a request, `sessions.Default(c)` is not available yet (see step 2 and step 7).

So it's naturally to add a middleware after the session middleware so that it can access and modify the session:

```golang
package m

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"

    "github.com/gin-contrib/sessions"
    "github.com/gin-contrib/sessions/memstore"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

// A handler that reads session data.
func handle(c *gin.Context) {
    session := sessions.Default(c)

    c.String(http.StatusOK, session.Get("sessionId").(string))
}

func TestSession(t *testing.T) {
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    c, engine := gin.CreateTestContext(w)

    memStore := memstore.NewStore([]byte("secret"))
    engine.Use(sessions.Sessions("session", memStore))

    // Add a middleware after the session middleware so that it can
    // access and modify the session.
    sessionId := uuid.NewString()
    engine.Use(gin.HandlerFunc(func(c *gin.Context) {
        session := sessions.Default(c)
        session.Set("sessionId", sessionId)
        c.Next()
    }))

    engine.GET("/session", handle)

    c.Request = httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "http://localhost/session", nil)
    engine.HandleContext(c)

    if buf, err := io.ReadAll(w.Body); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    } else if string(buf) != sessionId {
        t.Errorf("got sessionId %q, want %q", buf, sessionId)
    }
}
```

**Notes**: Since the session is touched in the test, if there is something wrong with the session, maybe the test can not catch it. So don't forget to add a test to make an request to let it create the real session, and pass the cookies from this request (let's assume it uses cookies) to the next request that will read from the session.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Why is it better to store uuid in session as string?

Comment: At first I thought that it will be written to / read from a cookie, so it seems that a string is easier to handle. But in fact, I haven't touched that part. And even taking cookie into account, it's not necessary better.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! All worked correctly (I didn't fully copy your code, I make some changes in my according to your answer :))

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It's a good habit that you do not copy demo code directly. It's just used for showing ideas and is not fully tested after all.