# how to pass json in postman -> form-data

Tags: go, go-gin, libpq

I have an application written in go, gin and libpq
this application connects to an azure storage account, and can list containers/blobs, delete blobs and create new blobs

the problem is when I need to insert new blobs, when inserting the blobs in the azure container, I also need to insert the data of these blobs in a database
I need to more specifically enter the name of the blob (which will be a random uuid)
my code:

```
func NewBlob() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        err := godotenv.Load(".env")
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Erro ao carregar variavel de ambiente", err)
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                "Erro ao carregar variavel de ambiente": err,
            })
            return
        }

        accountKey := os.Getenv("ACCOUNTKEY")
        storageAccountName := os.Getenv("ACCOUNTNAME")
        containerName := os.Getenv("CONTAINERNAME")

        // Obtem os arquivos enviados pelo cliente
        err = c.Request.ParseMultipartForm(50 << 20) //Tamanho maximo suportador pelo gin (envio de formulario)
        if err != nil {
            stringErrorParse := fmt.Sprintf("Erro ao obter arquivos: %s", err.Error())

            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                "Erro ao obter arquivos": stringErrorParse,
            })
            log.Println("Erro ao obter arquivos", stringErrorParse)
            return
        }

        // Conecta a conta de armazenamento do Azure
        client, err := storage.NewBasicClient(storageAccountName, accountKey)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Erro ao criar cliente: ", err)
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                "Erro ao criar cliente: ": err,
            })
            return
        }

        // Obtem uma referência para o contêiner de armazenamento
        blobService := client.GetBlobService()
        container := blobService.GetContainerReference(containerName)

        userIDJWT := c.GetInt("userIDJWT")
        var azureData []models.InsertAzure
        err = c.ShouldBindJSON(&azureData)
        if err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                "Erro ao decodificar body": err.Error(),
            })
            log.Println("Erro ao decodificar body", err)
            return
        }

        preparing, err := DB.Prepare(`INSERT INTO sis_documento (id_empresa, nome_documento, id_usuario_inclusao) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING id_documento, uuid_documento, link_documento `)
        if err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                "Erro ao preparar banco de dados para realizar insert na tabela sis_documento": err,
            })
            log.Println("Erro ao preparar banco de dados para realizar insert na tabela sis_documento", err)
            return
        }

        // Itera sobre cada arquivo enviado pelo cliente
        for _, fileHeaders := range c.Request.MultipartForm.File {

            for _, fileHeader := range fileHeaders {
                BlobName := uuid.New().String()
                // Abre o arquivo para leitura
                src, err := fileHeader.Open()
                if err != nil {
                    stringErrorHeader := fmt.Sprintf("Erro ao abrir arquivo: %s", err.Error())
                    c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                        "Error": stringErrorHeader,
                    })
                    log.Println("Error", stringErrorHeader)
                    return
                }
                defer src.Close()

                // Carrega o arquivo para o contêiner
                blob := container.GetBlobReference(BlobName)
                err = blob.CreateBlockBlobFromReader(src, &storage.PutBlobOptions{})
                if err != nil {
                    c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                        "Erro ao realizar upload do blob": err,
                    })
                    log.Fatal("Erro ao realizar upload do blob: ", err)
                    return
                }

                stringStatusOK := fmt.Sprintf("Arquivo %s enviado com sucesso!", BlobName)
                c.JSON(http.StatusOK, stringStatusOK)
            }
        }

        for _, add := range azureData {
            fmt.Println("Eu entrei no loop")

            _, err := preparing.Exec(1, add.NomeDocumento, userIDJWT)
            if err != nil {
                c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                    "Erro ao executar insert na tabela sis_documento": err,
                })
                log.Println("Erro ao executar insert na tabela sis_documento", err)
                return
            }
            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
                "Success, blob inserdo no banco com sucesso": preparing,
            })
        }
    }
}
```

that is, I need to send a json + files via postman, I try to send it through postman following the steps:
[image]

but I always get the error:

```
Erro ao decodificar body EOF
```

what i want is:
send my files + fill my json to populate my database (this will be necessary because I will get the file name, file type, file link among other variables)

EDIT:

I tried using the examples from this link:
[Golang gin receive json data and image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75987082/golang-gin-receive-json-data-and-image)

I made this test code:

```
func Test() gin.HandlerFunc {
return func(c *gin.Context) {
    prepare, err := DB.Prepare(`INSERT INTO sis_documento (id_empresa, nome_documento, id_usuario_inclusao) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Erro ao preparar banco de dados para realizar insert", err)
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "Erro ao preparar banco de dados para realizar insert": err,
        })
        return
    }

    var azureTesting []models.TestAzure
    userIDJWT := c.GetInt("userIDJWT")

    err = c.ShouldBind(&azureTesting, binding.FormMultipart)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Erro ao decodificar body da requisição", err)
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "Erro ao decodificar body da requisição": err,
        })
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(azureTesting)

    for _, add := range azureTesting {
        _, err := prepare.Exec(1, add.NomeDocumento, userIDJWT)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Erro ao preparar banco de dados para realizar insert", err)
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                "Erro ao preparar banco de dados para realizar insert": err,
            })
            return
        }
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "Success": add,
        })
    }
}
```

}

struct:

```
type TestAzure struct {
NomeDocumento string `json:"nome_documento" form:"nome_documento" binding:"required"`
```

}

but my code always printed an empty slice of my struct, it didn't populate the struct and it didn't enter my for

I tried to make the request like this:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang gin receive json data and image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75987082/golang-gin-receive-json-data-and-image)

Comment: The error is in the implementation of the server. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75989469/1369400) for the solution to parse files and json data from a `multipart/form-data` request. The usage of postman here looks correct except that the content-type of the second field should not be `multipart/form-data`. It's the whole request that has the content-type `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: I edited my question, I couldn't get the expected results, can you guys have a look? 
@ZekeLu

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```golang
var data struct {
    AzureTesting []struct {
        NomeDocumento string `json:"nome_documento" binding:"required"`
    } `form:"azureTesting"`
}
err = c.ShouldBind(&data, binding.FormMultipart)
```

And in postman, reset the "Content type" to `auto`. The content type of the field `azureTesting` is not `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass in JSON data to an application in postman, you must select raw format and then select JSON from the dropdown that appears.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass in JSON data to an application in postman, you can go to raw and enter the form data as key value pair

```
{
"azureTesting" : "nome_documento", "teste", ...
}
```