# array from form-data in golang return as a string instead of array

Tags: go, postman, multipartform-data, go-gin

I am passing an array from form data in postman, before the `json.Marsal` I get  `[0558485290,0209739442]` after the `json.Marshal` when I print using `(bytes.NewBuffer(jsonpayload))` I get `["0558485290,0209739442"]`

[image: postman request]

Before JSON Marshal
`[05583485362290,02097343639442]`
After json.Marshal
`"Recipient":["0558485290,0209739442"]`
Below Here is my code

```
type QuickBulkVoiceCall struct {
    Campaign      string                `form:"campaign"`
    Recipient     []string              `form:"recipient"`
    FileHeader    *multipart.FileHeader `form:"file_header"`
    File          string                `form:"file"`
    VoiceID       string                `form:"voice_id"`
    Is_Schedule   bool                  `form:"is_schedule"`
    Schedule_Date string                `form:"schedule_date"`
}
func (mnfyCmpgn *MnotifyCampaignService) CreateBulkVoiceCall(blkVcall *models.QuickBulkVoiceCall) (*mnotify.SMSData, error) {

    api_key, base_url, err := mnotify.LoadAPIKeys()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error: %v", err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Println("Before JSON Marshal", blkVcall.Recipient)

    jsonPayload, err := json.Marshal(blkVcall)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error: %v", err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Println("JSON Payload: ", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonPayload))

    url := (*base_url + "voice/quick/" + "?key=" + *api_key)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonPayload))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error: %v", err.Error())
    }
    // req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    // Make the HTTP Request
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error: %v", err.Error())
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error: %v", err)
    }
    responseBody := string(body)

    data, err := mnotify.BulkCampaignFilterFilter(responseBody)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error: %v", err)
    }

    return &data, nil
}
func (mnfyCmpgn *MnotifyCampaignController) QuickBulkVoiceCallController(ctx *gin.Context) {
    var blkVcCall *models.QuickBulkVoiceCall

    err := ctx.ShouldBind(&blkVcCall)
    if err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "error": err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    file, err := ctx.FormFile("file_header")
    if err != nil {
        // Handle the error if the file is not found
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    // Save file to the Uploads directory
    filePath := filepath.Join("./uploads", blkVcCall.FileHeader.Filename)
    if err := ctx.SaveUploadedFile(file, filePath); err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": err.Error(),
        })
    }

    //

    fmt.Println("Recipient", blkVcCall.Recipient)

    // Lets assign the file path to the struct file
    blkVcCall.File = filePath

    resp, err := mnfyCmpgn.Mnfycntrl.CreateBulkVoiceCall(blkVcCall)
    if err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "error": err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "response": resp,
    })
}
```

Comment: Please check the help section, specifically the page about how to ask a good question. You're expected to show _code_, efforts you've taken to fix your problem, and a clear description of the problem, and where you're stuck. Saying you have _"a postman request of an array"_ and _"I print X I get Y"_ without a clear question/problem statement, it's impossible to answer

Answer (score 1):

#### About the Print Output

> before the `json.Marsal` I get `[0558485290,0209739442]` after the `json.Marshal` when I print using `(bytes.NewBuffer(jsonpayload))` I get `["0558485290,0209739442"]`

Please note that the value is

`[]string{"0558485290,0209739442"}`

instead of

`[]string{"0558485290", "0209739442"}`.

See this simple demo:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    recipients := []string{"0558485290,0209739442"}
    fmt.Println(recipients) // [0558485290,0209739442]

    recipients = []string{"0558485290", "0209739442"}
    fmt.Println(recipients) // [0558485290 0209739442]
}
```

#### Send Array in `multipart/form-data` Request

To send an array to the server in a `multipart/form-data` request, you can do it like this:

```
curl 'https://httpbin.org/anything' \
    --form 'recipient="0558485290"' \
    --form 'recipient="0209739442"' \
    --form 'file_header=@"test.data"'
```

The corresponding request in postman is:

[image: postman request: form fields]

#### Send Array as JSON value in `multipart/form-data` Request

`gin` does not support JSON in `multipart/form-data` request very well. As of now, `gin` tries to unmarshal a JSON value in a `multipart/form-data` field only when the target field is a struct or a map (see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75989469/1369400). In the OP's case, the target field is a slice, so it does not work. BTW, `05583485362290,02097343639442` is not a valid JSON array (it's even not a valid JSON value). The valid JSON array should be: `["05583485362290","02097343639442"]`.

If you want to pass it as a JSON value, you have to unmarshal the value yourself. See the demo below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type QuickBulkVoiceCall struct {
    Recipient  []string
    FileHeader *multipart.FileHeader `form:"file_header"`
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.POST("/create", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        type temp struct {
            QuickBulkVoiceCall
            Recipient string `form:"recipient"`
        }
        var data temp
        err := ctx.ShouldBind(&data)
        if err != nil {
            ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
                "error": err.Error(),
            })
            return
        }

        blkVcCall := data.QuickBulkVoiceCall

        err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data.Recipient), &blkVcCall.Recipient)
        if err != nil {
            ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
                "error": err.Error(),
            })
            return
        }

        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", blkVcCall)
    })
    r.Run()
}
```

Here is the request to send the JSON value in a `multipart/form-data` field:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/create' \
    --form 'recipient="[\"0558485290\",\"0209739442\"]"' \
    --form 'file_header=@"test.data"'
```

And here is the corresponding postman request:

[image: postman request: JSON value]